# Error handling: different response format for REST API and web pages

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, error-handling, spring-boot

I'm adding some web pages and associated controllers to an existing REST API project.

In the existing project error handling is implementing via a `@ControllerAdvice` class, having several specific `@ExceptionHandler` methods and a custom `ErrorController` implementation (to customize default error controller provided by Spring Boot).

As expected, all these methods are returning error data in JSON, so every time an error occurs I'm receiving a JSON object as response, even in (web) controllers.

I'd like to distinguish among API errors and "web" errors. Or it could be better to generate response in a consistent format according to request format.

Which is the common way to acheve this? Should I implement different error handling for API and web areas or should I simply verify request format?
Can you provide any example?

Comment: i don't think separating web and API errors from same context is possible , you can do one thing though you can create a custom run time exception for web errors , and handle it separately in controller advice.

Comment: When dealing with web its better to have a consistent format so as not to let the consumer predict the error source (recommendation from PEN test). In this scenario you can have same response for every exception with corresponding error codes / messages as applicable

Answer (score 0):

It's easy using JSON views. Assuming the method returns a `ModelAndView`, if it's a web request you return a regular view (= a web page):

```
ModelAndView modelAndView = new ModelAndView("myView");
```

If it's a REST request (or AJAX request) you return a JSON view:

```
MappingJackson2JsonView jsonView = new MappingJackson2JsonView();
jsonView.setExtractValueFromSingleKeyModel(true);
ModelAndView modelAndView = new ModelAndView(jsonView);
modelAndView.addObject(myResponseObject);
```

In this case Spring does not return a page, but a JSON response that represents the object that you provided.